# I get buttons instead of radio buttons?

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a project with angular JS and i need to make a list of radio buttons to allow the user change the basemap. But i get the list without the circle of the radio button. My controller is like so:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('gdrtApp')
    .controller('MapController', MapController);

MapController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'olData'];

function MapController ($scope, $http, olData) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
        center: {
            lat: 47.383474,
            lon: 1.329346,
            zoom: 6,
            autodiscover: true
        },
        layers: [
            {
                name: 'OpenStreetMap',
                active: true,
                source: {
                    type: 'OSM',
                    url: "http://{a-c}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Stamen',
                active: false,
                source: {
                    type: 'Stamen',
                    layer: 'terrain'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Bing Maps Road',
                active: false,
                source: {
                    name: 'Bing Maps',
                    type: 'BingMaps',
                    key: 'Aj6XtE1Q1rIvehmjn2Rh1LR2qvMGZ-8vPS9Hn3jCeUiToM77JFnf-kFRzyMELDol',
                    imagerySet: 'Road'
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'Mapbox Geography Class',
                active: false,
                source: {
                    type: 'TileJSON',
                    url: 'http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mapbox.geography-class.jsonp'
                }
            }
        ],  
        changeLayer: function(layer) {
            $scope.layers.map(function(l) {
                l.active = (l === layer);
            });
        }
    });
  }
})();
```

My html file is like below:

```
<nav id="couches">
            <md-radio-group>
                <md-radio-button ng-repeat="layer in layers" ng-click="changeLayer(layer)">{{ layer.name }}<br/></md-radio-button>
            </md-radio-group>
        </nav>
```

When i execute, i get just list of the names of the layers and when i click on a layer's name i see the layer correctly. But no radio buttons ! What should i fix to solve this problem?

Comment: You should assign `ng-model`

Comment: @RameshRajendran How to assign ng-model plz? I'm new on angularJS.